# Change button image source when clicked if textField value matches

Tags: javascript, button, dom-events, textfield, src

What the code is supposed to do is, when clicked compare the textField value with the given value and change the source of the clicked button accordingly.

It doesn't do that. I can't seem to find why.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
function check(){
    var txt = document.getElementById('t1').value;

    if(txt == "had"){
    document.getElementById('tick').src = "button-check_basic_green.png";}
    else{document.getElementById('tick').src = "button-check_basic_red.png";}   
};

var press = document.getElementById('tick');
press.addEventListener("click", check);

</script>


<p>You <input type="text" id="t1">one job.</p><input type="image" 
src="button-check_basic_blue.png" id="tick"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at my updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/36j3ppsa/1):

JS:

```
function check() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('t1').value;

    if (txt === "had") {
        document.getElementById('tick').src = "button-check_basic_green.png";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('tick').src = "button-check_basic_red.png";
    }
};

window.onload = function() {
    var press = document.getElementById('tick');
    press.addEventListener("click", check);
}
```

EDITED with colored images

EDITED 2 for window.onload

Comment: The JSFiddle looks good but the code does not work. Can it be a problem with my browser?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Me too and it works fine, when I click the button it changes according to the value of the input. What's wrong?

Comment: It's not working because you call the JS in the head and the DOM is not still ready. you should wrap the last two lines in a `window.onload` function or place the script in the footer.